# Swift 3 Core Data - NSExpression forFunction: "sum:" throws error ("could not cast dictionary to Day")

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I have days and tasks. A day has many tasks. Every task has an attribute called "points" and I want to sum all points of the tasks of the current day. I used the code below (found in the book Core Data by tutorials, swift 2 version) and tried to modify it for swift 3 (I also added a predicate, but that's not important). But when I run this code, I get this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'NSKnownKeysDictionary1' (0x10d02d328) to 'MyProject.Day'

What am I doing wrong?

```
    // sum current day's task points 
    let sumRequest: NSFetchRequest<Day> = Day.fetchRequest()
    sumRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

    sumRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF == %@", argumentArray: [Project.Days.current])

    let expressionDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
    expressionDescription.name = "sumOfPoints"
    expressionDescription.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [NSExpression(forKeyPath: "tasks.points")])
    expressionDescription.expressionResultType = .integer16AttributeType

    sumRequest.propertiesToFetch = [expressionDescription]

    do {
        let results = try managedObject.fetch(sumRequest) as! [NSDictionary] // Here's the line that causes the error
        print("DEN:", results)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("DEN:", error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

I think it has something to do with this line:

```
let sumRequest: NSFetchRequest<Day> = Day.fetchRequest()
```

Here, I explicitly say the result will be a Day (I believe that's new in swift 3?). But I don't know how I could change this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solves my problem:

```
let sumRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Day.fetchRequest()
```

Instead of putting `Day`as `NSFetchRequestResult`, I put `NSFetchRequestResult` itself there. Now it's working.

I believe as I set it to a different `resultType` it's not `[Day]`anymore that gets returned, so that's why I needed to change that to be more generic or something.