# KVC Error Fetching Aggregate Property

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, nsfetchrequest

I've looked both on Google and through SE and could not find the answer to my question, so my apologies if I overlooked what might be a simple solution. I'm still green, so I probably didn't use the right search terms. :)

Okay, I feel like I'm 99% to where I want to be. I have the following class function:

```
class func fetchGroupTotal(_ group: Int, for managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Double {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Group> = Group.fetchRequest()
    let keyPathExpression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "accounts.balance")
    let sumExpression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [keyPathExpression])
    let expressionDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
    expressionDescription.name = "groupSum"
    expressionDescription.expression = sumExpression
    expressionDescription.expressionResultType = .decimalAttributeType
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [expressionDescription]
    fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

    do {
        let results = try managedObjectContext.execute(fetchRequest)
        print("\(results)")
        return results.value(forKey: "groupSum") as! Double
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error fetching SUM: \(error)")
    }
}
```

In short, I'm trying to do a `sum` on the `accounts` relationship, and that part seems to be working. The problem happens when I try to access the `groupSum` property that I defined. I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
'[<NSAsynchronousFetchResult 0x600000288de0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not 
key value coding-compliant for the key groupSum.'
```

How do I go about getting my `groupSum` from the results?

Answer (score 0):

Whew! That was a rough hour there, but after many failed Google searches, I finally found [found my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39527348/918534). Once I made the change to how I declared my `fetchRequest`, I was then able to access my `groupSum` property as an `[NSDictionary]`.

For those who might be interested, here is the final version of my function:

```
class func fetchTotal(_ group: Int, for managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Double {

    // Right here is where the magic happens:
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Group.fetchRequest()

    let keyPathExpression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "accounts.balance")
    let sumExpression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [keyPathExpression])
    let expressionDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
    expressionDescription.name = "groupSum"
    expressionDescription.expression = sumExpression
    expressionDescription.expressionResultType = .decimalAttributeType
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [expressionDescription]
    fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true

    do {
        let results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest).first
        if let result = results as? NSDictionary {
            return result.value(forKey: "groupSum") as! Double
        }
        return 0.00
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error fetching SUM: \(error)")
    }
}
```